# How to update the BIOS of an asus a3tiont motherboard?

Tags: bios, updates

How to update the BIOS of an asus a3tiont motherboard?

I have no clue. Formerly I had to use a floppy drive, etc. But this I don't have any!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked whether the current BIOS has EZ-Flash (or similar) built in? If so, you can update from USB stick or CD. It is also possible to make a bootable USB stick to help you run DOS-based BIOS update tools:

http://www.bootdisk.com/pendrive.htm